# Plotly Dash: Download local file on button click

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to link a local file to my Dash button but cannot get it to work.

I've tried a few combos, like turning off the `'external_link'` tag or placing the file into an assets folder, but nothing seems to work, although the problem seems to be extremely simple. I'm following the syntax from the [Dash Bootstrap Button documentation](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/button/).

How can I get this file linked up?

```
dbc.Button(
    "download",
    href='xxx.xlsx',
    external_link=True,
    color="primary",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the dumb question - turned out the file had to the be in the /static/ folder for it to work - cannot just link up any random file on the drive